# Pythonic way to iterate 2D arrays contained in 3D array on a specific axis

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a 3D float numpy array and wish to iterate over the 2D planes in it on a specific axis.

`for 2D in 3D:` iterates over the axis 0. So 2D  will be 3D[0,:,:]   3D[1,:,:] etc. at each iteration. How can I specify the axis to get 3D[:,:,0]   3D[:,:,1] etc

Comment: You need to give a bit more context here. Are you talking about a numpy array perhaps? The Python standard library has no types that support tuple indexing, or axes.

Comment: Sorry you are right of course. Numpy arrays, yes

Comment: I just reviewed that other question before asking this one in fact I thought it was more about time efficiency. It might be my poor python knowledge, I couldn't really understand the syntax to do this there, and concluded maybe it is not there at all, since the question was about timing :(

Comment: The question there is not about timing. That the accepted answer chose to focus on timing is only to explain why `.swapaxis()` is a good approach, and so is using a `range(array.shape[...])` loop.